# Membership Server Control in Ektron

Tags: ektron

Is it possible to customize Membership Server Control? I need only First Name,Last Name and Email field with the Submit and Reset Button in the form and I don't need any tabs for the server control.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Membership Control is limited in terms of the customisations you can make.  Your best bet is to create an ASPX form that has the fields you need and then to use the Framework API (Ektron.Cms.Framework.User) to create / edit membership users.

You can find all of Ektron's documentation [here](http://documentation.ektron.com).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the User Manager of the framework API
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/edr/web/edr.htm#FrameworkAPI/User/UserManager.htm%3FTocPath%3D
Framework%2520API%7CUser%7C_____2

Here's a sample.

```
            long UserId = 0;
            //user manager is using the API access mode of admin to retrieve the user which overrides the logged in user permission
            Ektron.Cms.Framework.User.UserManager uManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.User.UserManager(Ektron.Cms.Framework.ApiAccessMode.Admin);
            var uData = uManager.GetItem(UserId);
            string fn = uData.FirstName;
            string ln = uData.LastName;
            string email = uData.Email;
            uData.Email = "";
            uData.FirstName = "";
            uData.LastName = "";
            uManager.Update(uData);
```